# How to truncate text using CSS on mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, truncate

Is there a way via CSS to truncate text based on the current screen size/media queries? For example I have this paragraph of text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tortor
vitae nisl tincidunt varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Ut vel ullamcorper tortor. Nullam vel turpis a augue tempor 
posuere vel quis nibh. Nam ultrices felis turpis, at commodo ipsum tristique 
non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae; Suspendisse in accumsan dui, finibus pharetra est. Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae velit eu dui 
rutrum pellentesque vel imperdiet sem. Morbi ut lacinia lacus, in commodo 
nibh. Sed cursus ante ut nunc molestie viverra.
```

Using CSS, can I truncate the text above based on the device they are viewing the page with? So if on a mobile device, it would truncate like so:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tortor 
vitae nisl tincidunt varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Ut vel ullamcorper...
```

I found this option, but it only seems to work with width. So only one line of text would show. I simply just want to show so many letters based off the current device they are viewing the page on.

```
.truncate-ellipsis {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.truncate-ellipsis > * {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<div class="truncate-ellipsis">
    <span>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tortor vitae nisl tincidunt varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel ullamcorper tortor. Nullam vel turpis a augue tempor posuere vel quis nibh. Nam ultrices felis turpis, at commodo ipsum tristique non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse in accumsan dui, finibus pharetra est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae velit eu dui rutrum pellentesque vel imperdiet sem. Morbi ut lacinia lacus, in commodo nibh. Sed cursus ante ut nunc molestie viverra.
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible without js. https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/hub/blogs/ellipse-my-text/ || https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow.

Comment: Well it is possible with CSS if you want to take advantage of `-webkit-line-clamp: 6;` with the `flex` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `flex` to achieve multiple line truncation. On large devices it will truncate after 6 lines while for <768px it will truncate after 3 lines.

```css
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 6;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  p{
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tortor
vitae nisl tincidunt varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Ut vel ullamcorper tortor. Nullam vel turpis a augue tempor 
posuere vel quis nibh. Nam ultrices felis turpis, at commodo ipsum tristique 
non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae; Suspendisse in accumsan dui, finibus pharetra est. Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae velit eu dui 
rutrum pellentesque vel imperdiet sem. Morbi ut lacinia lacus, in commodo 
nibh. Sed cursus ante ut nunc molestie viverra.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tortor
vitae nisl tincidunt varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Ut vel ullamcorper tortor. Nullam vel turpis a augue tempor 
posuere vel quis nibh. Nam ultrices felis turpis, at commodo ipsum tristique 
non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
cubilia Curae; Suspendisse in accumsan dui, finibus pharetra est. Lorem ipsum 
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae velit eu dui 
rutrum pellentesque vel imperdiet sem. Morbi ut lacinia lacus, in commodo 
nibh. Sed cursus ante ut nunc molestie viverra.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 filter('textLimit', function () {
        return function (text, length) {
            if (text.length > length) {
                return text.substr(0, length) + "<span>...</span>";
            }
            return text;
        }
    $scope.text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam porta tortor
    vitae nisl tincidunt varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
    adipiscing elit. Ut vel ullamcorper tortor. Nullam vel turpis a augue tempor 
    posuere vel quis nibh. Nam ultrices felis turpis, at commodo ipsum tristique 
    non. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere 
    cubilia Curae; Suspendisse in accumsan dui, finibus pharetra est. Lorem ipsum 
    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae velit eu dui 
    rutrum pellentesque vel imperdiet sem. Morbi ut lacinia lacus, in commodo 
    nibh. Sed cursus ante ut nunc molestie viverra".

    <span > {{text |textLimit :50}} </span>
```

Comment: The OP asked for CSS not javascript.